# Checking if a number has an integer cubic root

Tags: vba

I am trying to check whether a given number is cuberoot or not in VBA.
The following code works only for 2 and 3 as answers, it does not work after that.
I am trying to figure out what is wrong in the code.

```
Sub cuberoot()
    Dim n As Long, p As Long, x As Long, y As Long

    x = InputBox("x= ")
    If Iscube(x) Then
        MsgBox ("Is cube")
    Else
        MsgBox ("No cube")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function Iscube(a As Long) As Boolean
    b = a ^ (1 / 3)
    If b = Int(b) Then
        Iscube = True
    Else
        Iscube = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If I input `125`, which is the cube root of `5`, I correctly get the answer `Is cube` even if you're saying that it works only for `2` and `3`. I think you should clarify what is the input, the output you expect and the output you get for us to understand what you mean. Otherwise, I can only say that _given your description, your code should work fine_.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ without dimension b as long the code above fails for me as int(b) returns 4.

Comment: @Apurva I hope you've found the answer to your question.  If so, it is customary here to accept the answer which provided the best solution to your problem.  You can read more about that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing in a `Long` I'll assume that you won't have a number bigger than roughly 2*10^9 so this should always work.  It's a slight variation where you truncate the double and then compare to the two nearest integers to make sure you catch any rounding errors.

Edit: In VBA the truncating would always round so it's only neccessary to check the 3rd root value:

```
Public Function Iscube(a As Long) As Boolean

Dim b As Integer
b = CInt(a ^ (1# / 3#))

If (b ^ 3 = a) Then
    Iscube = True
Else
    Iscube = False
End If

End Function
```

If you need a number larger than a `Long` you'll need to change your input type and you might want to consider an iterative method like a binary search or a Newton-Raphson solver instead.

Answer (score 1):

*Existing Code*

Your code will work if you add a
`dim b as long`

If you debug your code you will see that feeding in 125 gives you

> b = 5
>   Int(b) = 4

*Updated Code*

You can shorten your boolean test to this

```
Function Iscube(lngIn As Long) As Boolean
Iscube = (Val(lngIn ^ (1 / 3)) = Int(Val(lngIn ^ (1 / 3))))
End Function
```

Note that if you call it with a double, it will opearte on the long portion only (so it would see `IsCube(64.01)`as `IsCube(64)`)